# Recommended Javascript Conventions

Tags: javascript, coding-style, naming-conventions, conventions

Looking for a recommended Javascript convention to use while writing Javascript Libraries.

Javascript Style  Validators / Beautifiers that will help me enforce it will be welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

**Code Conventions Guides:**

1. [Crockford's Code Conventions for the JavaScript Programming Language](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)
2. [Google JavaScript Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml)

with an exception of using `$varname` to indicate a jQuery (or whatever library) object. E.g.

```
var footer = document.getElementById('footer');

var $footer = $('#footer');
```

*originally recommanded by "Deebster".*

**Code Validation Tools:**

1. [JsLint - Online Code Quality Tool](http://www.jslint.com/)
2. [Closure Linter - Enforces the guidelines set by the Google JavaScript Style Guide (Python Based)](https://developers.google.com/closure/utilities/docs/linter_howto?hl=iw&csw=1)

**Additional Sources:**

[More JavaScript Style Guides And Beautifiers](http://addyosmani.com/blog/javascript-style-guides-and-beautifiers/)